# Service to monitor S.M.A.R.T. HDDs and send email on failure

Tags: windows, smart

What software would you recommend that I can install on a Windows 7 machine that runs as an unattended server (with usually nobody logged on) that would monitor SMART HDD attributes for signs of failure and send email notification when drive starts to fail?

Answer (score 2):

So many options. But search for "smart monitor windows" and you may be able to find something that meets your needs.

Also: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_S.M.A.R.T._tools

One thing to note: most drive failures aren't caught by SMART monitoring. Do you have any RAID solution in this setup? Chances are that you'd experience data loss before detecting major errors in a single-disk setup.

Comment: I've had good success with Acronis Drive Monitor, which also happens to be alphabetically first on that list ;)